# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username') in Postman

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I try to make login and register using express, sequelize, and mysql. the code is running but when i try to send POST request on Postman, it throws an error `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')"`

I think there's an error in userRepository.js but i dont know where is it.

Here is the code

```
const { Op } = require('sequelize');
const { user, Sequelize } = require('../models');


const createUser = async (req, res) => {
    const User = await user.create({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password,
      role: req.body.role,
    });
  
   //await User.save();
    return User;
  };
  
  const getUserByUsername = async (username) => {
    return user.findOne({ where: {username} });
  };
  
  const getUserByEmail = async (email) => {
    return user.findOne({ where: {email} });
  };
  
  module.exports = {
    createUser,
    getUserByUsername,
    getUserByEmail,
  };
```

here is userService.js

```
const userRepository = require('../repositories/userRepository');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const registerUser = async (data) => {
  //const { username, email, password } = data;
  
  const existingUserByUsername = await userRepository.getUserByUsername(data.username);
  if (existingUserByUsername) {
    throw new Error('Username already exists');
  }

  const existingUserByEmail = await userRepository.getUserByEmail(data.email);
  if (existingUserByEmail) {
    throw new Error('Email already exists');
  }

  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10);
  const User = await userRepository.createUser({
    username: data.username,
    email: data.email,
    password: hashedPassword,
    role: data.role
  });

  return User;
};

const loginUser = async (data) => {
  //const { username, password } = data;

  const User = await userRepository.getUserByUsername(data.username);
  if (!User) {
    throw new Error('User not found');
  }

  const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(data.password, User.password);
  if (!isPasswordValid) {
    throw new Error('Invalid password');
  }

  const token = jwt.sign({ userId: User.id }, 'JWT_SECRET');
  return token;
};

module.exports = {
  registerUser,
  loginUser
};
```

and here is userController.js

```
const userService = require('../services/userService');

const register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const User = await userService.registerUser(req.body);
    return res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      message: 'User created successfully',
      data: User
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (
      err.message === 'Username already exists' ||
      err.message === 'Email already exists'
    ) {
      return res.status(409).json({ 
        status: 'error',
        error: err.message
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({ 
        status: 'error',
        error: err.message
        // message: 'Internal Server Error',
        // data: err
      });
    }
  }
};

const login = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const token = await userService.loginUser(req.body);
    return res.json({ 
      status: 'success',
      message: 'User logged in successfully',
      data: token
    });
  } catch (err) {
    if (
      err.message === 'User not found' ||
      err.message === 'Invalid password' 
    ) {
      return res.status(401).json({ 
        status: 'error',
        error: err.message
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(500).json({ 
        status: 'error',
        message: 'Internal Server Error',
        data: err
      });
    }
  }
};

module.exports = {
  register,
  login
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: can we see the code that calls `createUser`?

Comment: i just edit and add the full codes in the question, i still dont know why it throws the same error @BagusTesa

Answer (score 0):

you can console.log(req.body) in top of function to see this problem from postman or logic code. If it undefined. There is 2 issue I can provide you to check.

1. Are you config right bodyparser in server?
2. Are you send right data in body in postman

Comment: i already add this on my server.js

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: you pass an object into function call createUser right?. So why you call req.body.username in function createUser declare?. It only req.username I think

Comment: the object you pass in has 4 property only. It not have property name body that why it undefined

Comment: or you can only pass in {body: data} when call function userCreate in userService file

Comment: I think it will solve your problem

Comment: oh right! it's solved, the problem is in req.body.username and it should be req.username. thank you